# Isomorphism and elements that are their own inverses

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can i determine that tow groups $G_1 , G_2$ are isomorphic to each other , if they have the same number of elements that they are their own inverses ($x=x^{-1}$ while $x \in G$) ?

If all their elements are their own inverses than its true, if only one element (except the identity ) than both of them are cyclic so they are isomorphic.

In any other case i thought maybe to show that their defining equations are the same ?

Thank you for your help :D

Comment: Any two groups of odd order have one element with this property (namely the identity).

Comment: In general the isomorphism types of groups are quite complicated and it is not at all easy to capture them using some straightforward list of invariants. For example I believe the complete list of orders of the elements still doesn't determine a finite group up to isomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

The groups $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ both have exactly two elements which equal their own inverse.  More generally, $\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z}$ has exactly two elements satisfying $x=x^{-1}$ for all $n\ge 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be any group, and let $H$ be any group of odd order; then $G\times H$ and $G$ have the same number of elements satisfying the equation $x=x^{-1}$. Specifically, $\langle x,y\rangle\in G\times H$ satisfies it if and only if $x$ does **and** $y=1_H$.

Answer (score 1):

For every abelian group $G$, $G$ is divisible if for every $x\in G$ there exists $g_n\in G$ such that the following equation is satisfied for all $n\ge1$:
$$ng_n=x$$
If we set $dG$ the subgroup of all divisible subgroup of a group $G$ then we can have $$G=dG\oplus G/dG$$

> Theorem: $$G\cong H\Longleftrightarrow dG\cong dH,~~\text{and}~~G/dG\cong H/dH$$